# I need to plot multiple mayavi plots in in one screen with ability to chose one at a time

Tags: python, visualization, vtk, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have a data frame in which has 11 columns the first 3 columns give me the x,y,z coordinates. The rest 8 columns I need to plot separately.

```
    mlab.plot3d(df['x_coordinate'],df['y_coordinate'],df['z_coordinate'],df['Fx'],tube_radius=1, colormap='copper', opacity = 0.5)
    mlab.show()
    mlab.plot3d(df['x_coordinate'],df['y_coordinate'],df['z_coordinate'],df['Fy'],tube_radius=0.5, colormap='spectral', opacity = 0.5)
    mlab.show()
```

This is an example code I am trying to plot two columns. I am satisfied with the result but with this, all the plots of "Fx", "Fy" are getting into one plot. I want a single screen but I want that I should be able to switch between "Fx" "Fy",,,,etc. As you can see in the image once I will plot all 8 columns then it will hard to read from one image.

[image]

Comment: the [volume slicer example](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_volume_slicer.html#example-volume-slicer) handles simultaneous views of the same data, you can check that out as reference